# Pandas: Rank Games according to score

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am fairly new to development in any platform. Trying to basics in Python - Pandas. When trying to practise about pandas groupby function, I am getting duplicate records. Please see the data, questions and code I tried. Appreciate any suggestions on the same.

1. read game.csv, game_score.csv

game.csv -

```
 id,url,genre,editors_choice,release_year,release_month,release_day
 0,/games/littlebigplanet-vita/vita-98907,Platformer,Y,2012,9,12
 1,/games/littlebigplanet-ps-vita-marvel-super-hero-edition/vita-20027059,Platformer,Y,2012,9,12
 2,/games/splice/ipad-141070,Puzzle,N,2012,9,12
 3,/games/nhl-13/xbox-360-128182,Sports,N,2012,9,11
 4,/games/nhl-13/ps3-128181,Sports,N,2012,9,11
 5,/games/total-war-battles-shogun/mac-     142565,Strategy,N,2012,9,11
 6,/games/double-dragon-neon/xbox-360-     131320,Fighting,N,2012,9,11
 7,/games/guild-wars-2/pc-896298,RPG,Y,2012,9,11
 8,/games/double-dragon-neon/ps3-131321,Fighting,N,2012,9,11
 9,/games/total-war-battles-shogun/pc-142564,Strategy,N,2012,9,11
 10,/games/tekken-tag-tournament-2/ps3-124584,Fighting,N,2012,9,11
```

game_score.csv

```
id,score_phrase,title,platform,score                                  
 0,Painful,The History Channel: Battle for the Pacific,Wii,2.5                                   
 1,Awful,The History Channel: Battle For the Pacific,PlayStation 2,3                                   
 2,Bad,The History Channel: Battle For The Pacific,PC,4.9                                   
 3,Bad,The History Channel: Battle For the Pacific,Xbox 360,4.5                                   
 4,Bad,The History Channel: Battle For the Pacific,PlayStation 3,4.5                                   
 5,Awful,Hail to the Chimp,Xbox 360,3.5                                   
 6,Awful,Hail To The Chimp,PlayStation 3,3.5                                   
 7,Okay,Spyro: Enter The Dragonfly,PlayStation 2,6                                   
 8,Okay,Spyro: Enter the Dragonfly,GameCube,6                                   
 9,Okay,007 Legends,PlayStation 2,4                                                                      
 10,Okay,007 Racing,GameCube,5
```

2. merger 2 csv files based on "id"
3. Find the mean score of each game using groupby
4. sort the values in descending order to determine the rank
5. store the file into a o/p csv file
6. o/p csv file contains columns title, score
7. do not include header while writing o/p csv file

My Code -

```
 import pandas as pd 
 file_game = pd.read_csv('game.csv')                                
 file_game_score = pd.read_csv('game_score.csv')                      
 merged_game_file = pd.merge(file_game, file_game_score,      on='id')      
 final_data = merged_game_file[['title', 'score']]      
 mean_df = final_data.groupby('title').mean()      
 final_df = mean_df['score'].rank(ascending=0)      
 print(final_df)
```

## O/P --- final_df

```
 007 Legends,4.5      
 007 Racing,7.0      
 Hail To The Chimp,2.5      
 Hail to the Chimp,2.5      
 Spyro: Enter The Dragonfly,8.5      
 Spyro: Enter the Dragonfly,8.5      
 The History Channel: Battle For The Pacific,6.0
 The History Channel: Battle For the Pacific,4.5
 The History Channel: Battle for the Pacific,1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HeRe iS oNe iDeA...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd 
file_game = pd.read_csv('game.csv')                                
file_game_score = pd.read_csv('game_score.csv') 



# make '...Battle For the Pacific' and '...Battle For The Pacific' the same
file_game_score['title'] = file_game_score['title'].str.lower()



merged_game_file = pd.merge(file_game, file_game_score, on='id')      
final_data = merged_game_file[['title', 'score']]      
mean_df = final_data.groupby('title').mean()      
final_df = mean_df['score'].rank(ascending=0)      
print(final_df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
title
007 legends                                    3.0
007 racing                                     2.0
hail to the chimp                              5.0
spyro: enter the dragonfly                     1.0
the history channel: battle for the pacific    4.0
```

Comment: Thanks @MDR. I learned this hard way. Spread sheet is not case sensitive where as Pandas are case sensitive. Thanks a lot for your time and help. 